# openldapforwindows.exe (OpenLDAP for windows) version 2.2.29

Tags: ldap, openldap

Can anyone tell me from where I can download openldapforwindows.exe (OpenLDAP for windows) version **2.2.29**? I tried various pages, but I was not able to get this particular version

Comment: This website doesnt offer download locations of random files and programmes, this is a community designed to help one another with specific technical MOSTLY coding issues. I have downvoted the question.

Comment: when I migrated from 2.2.29 to 2.4, openldap does not read the attributes specified in the custom schema file... it was working perfectly in 2.2.29...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you *solve the problem* instead of downgrading.

Your schema files need to be in DOS format not Unix format, i.e. line-terminated by \r\n.

Answer (score 0):

you can download openldap for windows from http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx